# Adding Fabric answers to a common library within the project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, twitter-fabric

I have a project which has a common library. This library is refereed to my base app and other libraries .

I need to integrate Fabrics Answers to a common class in Base library which i can use to call or refer from any module.
I tried adding Fabric answers to the Common Library, but it was throwing error in every module where this Common library is refereed.

The error was :-

```
Failed to resolve: com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10
```

How can i fix this issue.

Gradle for The Custom Library is :-

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 11
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/conceal_android.jar')
    compile files('libs/cordova-5.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/fbconnect.jar')
    compile files('libs/FlurryAgent.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jaxen-1.1-beta-6.jar')
    compile files('libs/libconceal.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.2.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

The error shown is :-

[image: Error Message]

How can i fix this issue. else ill have to always go and add this Answers to individual module and repeat the code

Comment: may be your android or google repository is not of updated version it happen due to that also

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="YOUR_FABRIC_API_KEY" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Its wrking already ... Fabric is wrking fr me.... I need to add it just to my library so tat i can use it a common class from anywhere